# How to use related_name property of a ForeignKey in a template

Tags: django

I can get query using this line when my foreign key does not have related_name:

```
 {{user.provider_set.all}}
```

but when I set a related_name for it it doesn't work anymore.
how should I get data now

Comment: is provider_set another model that has relation 1-many? What exception do you get with related_name?

Comment: Is something in the documentation on using related names in Querysets specifically confusing?

Comment: When you have a related_name, you *use* that related_name instead of provider_set. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome to Stack Overflow and I suggest reading [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before going further :)

You need to call with `related_name` you set. If you have `related_name='providers'` you can use `{{ user.providers.all }}`.

Also, [here is the relevant part of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) if you want to read more.